# Poison Encode encoding nested models

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Sup,

I'm trying to encode some nested Ecto Models but i have encountered a problem. I realised that i can't encode unloaded model and i want to have possibility of selecting only one structure without loading rest and at the same time having possibility of selecting whole tree.

I have used method with defimpl, example:

```
defimpl Poison.Encoder, for: Hangman.MasterCat do
    def encode(page, _options) do
      %{
        id: page.id,
        name: page.name,
        categories: page.categories
      } |> Poison.Encoder.encode([])
    end
  end
defimpl Poison.Encoder, for: Hangman.Category do
    def encode(category, _options) do
      IO.inspect(category.words)
      %{
        id: category.id,
        name: category.name,
        words: category.words
      } |> Poison.Encoder.encode([])
    end
  end
defimpl Poison.Encoder, for: Hangman.Word do
    def encode(page, _options) do
      %{
        content: page.content
      } |> Poison.Encoder.encode([])
    end
  end
```

This works for whole structure but it doesn't work for selecting only MasterCats and it gives such error.

```
cannot encode association :categories from Hangman.MasterCat to JSON because the association was not loaded. Please make sure you have preloaded the association or remove it from the data to be encoded
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define the same encoder for categories too and so on. In fact, there is an easier to do this, if you are using latest Poison, you can write:

```
defmodule Hangman.MasterCat do
  use Ecto.Model

  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:id, :name, :categories]}
  schema "..." do
```

This way, Elixir takes care of automatically implementing the protocol for you. As long as you derive the encoder for the types you care, you should be good. For complex cases, explicitly implementing the protocol, as you did, is the way to go.

Comment: I've already done that. I have problem with protocol requiring me to preload that i may not need at the moment. For example when i show list of Master Categories i don't want to show their children. But when i'm showing whole structure (for reasons) i need to show them.

Comment: You can always preload in the encoder, Ecto won't preload twice. But I would recommend you to preload properly as needed instead of doing it in the encoder.

Comment: Yeah, that what's im trying to do, but i may have again written my question wrong. Can i have more than one encoder per model? If no i got error when encoding not preloaded values which i'm trying to avoid.

Comment: If you want to have more than one encoder per model, than I would recommend you to use Phoenix views. Check what is generated by `mix phoenix.gen.json` as an example.